# How to hide "view source" options in website in wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want to hide view source options from my wordpress websites.

Please let me know how its possible to lock the view source options in wordpress sites.

Thank You

Comment: You can disable the right click button at max, but can't stop user from viewing the html source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't...the only thing you can do is disabling right clicks:

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false;">
```

However if the reader is more expert than a dog, he knows that a "View Sorce" button is also under "Tools" in the top bar...

Answer (score 2):

You cant 100% lock that option. The ones, who will want to know the source **will** find a workaround. The source is generated for client-side uses, so the visitors will **always** have access to it.

Your *best* option is to encode/decrypt your source, but I'm pretty sure you can't do that in wordpress.